# Behat how to create a multiple context

Tags: behat

**After** vendor/bin/behat --dry-run --append-snippets
**my behat.yml**
default:
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
        - FeatureContext
        - OneContext

**but context is not shown.** `enter code here`

Comment: Please provide more details. From the description it's not clear what you are doing and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: why we use behat.yml file in the behat.  if we not use yml file what will happens.  And give online tutorial not want a official docs.